# Azure Logic Apps Function Call SAP By BAPI always give me wrong feedback

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, bapi

I'm using Azure Logic Apps call SAP template, I use call BAPI method to send message to SAP. But, I got error feedback every time, it tells me that The provided request payload storage blob URI 'cn01' is not valid. cn01 is what I get from SAP GUI. I don't know if it is the right formate of BAPI parameters. If someone knows the right formate, please help me. Thank you.[image: screenshoot of input]

Comment: Shouldn't it be XML? Something like `<COMPANYCODEID>CN01</COMPANYCODEID>`? (be careful, it's case sensitive)

Comment: What would the input XML in case of a table parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pure deduction based on this [Microsoft documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/logic-apps/logic-apps-using-sap-connector.md#xml-samples-for-bapi-requests), after logging into a SAP S/4HANA system and running the transaction code `SWO1` I could check that "Company" corresponds to the Business Object `BUS0002`, that `BAPI_COMPANYCODE_GETDETAIL` corresponds to the method `GETDETAIL`, and the parameter name in the function module is named `COMPANYCODEID`, I'd say that the screen field **"Input BAPI Parameters"** should contain:

```
<GETDETAIL xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Bapi/BUS0002">
  <COMPANYCODEID>CN01</COMPANYCODEID>
</GETDETAIL>
```

But seeing that all those information are already in the screen fields "Business object" and "Method", maybe only this XML is relevant:

```
<COMPANYCODEID>CN01</COMPANYCODEID>
```

Comment: @zhangzhihao Could you confirm what the exact solution was?